# Save user login credential in Android. What is the best way?

Tags: android, security, passwords, keystore

I want that in my app after the user logged in, or signed in, the password, and other strings that i receive from my server, are stored in the device. So i'm thinking to encrypt this data whit the Keys that i receive from KeyStore. After i did that, where should i save my encrypted data?

I have also read that save password in local device is not the best pratice. Should i store it directly on the server? Here is an article that i read [HERE](http://www.androidauthority.com/where-is-the-best-place-to-store-a-password-in-your-android-app-597197/)

Comment: I reccomend use sharedPreference

Answer (score 0):

Everything goes over the server.When you login on the device ,store the users id(hash it on the server and return the hashed id to the device).Store that hashed id of your user in shared preferences or in a local database.And when you want to retrieve some data(for example user data) send the hashed id to the server ,unshash it on the server than make the query.

Comment: PS I prefere to do everything on a hard way so i make my own php scripts and everything goes the harder way.Also there is firebase as #oskarko suggested.

Comment: I need to store the password so i don't need to ask the user to re-login when the token is expired.

Comment: You didn't understand my answer.You are going in a wrong way with that approach.Just store the id of the user ,even when you make a regular login with php you store in a session the id of the user.Than every time when you go to that page you are logged in......

Comment: I alredy store the user id. I never use the password to call the functions on the server. When i signin for the first time i recive from the server uid, pass and token. When the app restart send the token to the server and check validation. if is valid i'm logged in. If the token is expired i use the stored password to make the login, and get the a new token. Maybe i haven't expleined my problem very well or i'm not understanding what you mean.

Comment: Than hash(with salt) the password on the server and return it to the device,and store it hashed on the device(as i already mentioned in my answer).Even if someone sees your password he/she would be unable to do anything with it since it's hashed.Than send that hasshed password....you know the rest i dont have to explain it....

Comment: (One more hash on the hashed password)

Comment: Ok, yes i got it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to keep the user data in the smartphone? Have you try Firebase?
and you're right! save password in the phone isn't the good way.

Try Firebase ;)

Comment: I have alredy a server where i make login and signin. From the app i call the server functions and receive password, uid, and other infos. I want to store the password so i don't need to ask the relogin at the user when the token is expired.